# Solve a Sturm-Liouville Boundary Value Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation, sturm-liouville

**Solve the Wave Equation**

I've been trying to solve the above wave equation 
where $u = u(x, t)$ and $c ∈ \mathbb{R}$ is a constant, subject to
$$
u(x, 0) = 0,\;\; 0 < x < 1, \\
u_t(x, 0) = U_0x,\;\; 0 < x < 1, \\
u(0, t) = 0, \;\; t > 0, \\
u(1, t) = 0, \;\; t > 0.
$$

I know that a Sturm-Liouville Boundary Value Problem for a function $y(x)$ on some interval $a ≤ x ≤ b$ is a two-point boundary value problem which satisfies the ODE but am unsure of how to use the information given to me to solve this wave equation as a Sturm-Liouville BVP.

Comment: I've edited your question. Please click on the edit button (you don't have to save,) and look at what I've done. I'm not the best at formatting, but it may give you an example to build on, and it does look a whole lot better than what you had, with a minimum amount of effort. Also, please check for accuracy; I hope I have not changed your problem.

Comment: What have you tried? the first step is presumably assuming $u=f(t)g(x)$ for functions $f,g$ you must solve for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After separation of variables, and enforcing homogeneous conditions,
$$
    u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \sin(n\pi c t)\sin(n\pi x).
$$
The condition $u_t(x,0)=U_0 x$ determines the constants $A_n$:
$$
     U_0 x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_nn\pi c\sin(n\pi x)
$$
The coefficients are determined by orthogonality of the functions $\sin(n\pi x)$:
$$
     U_0\int_{0}^{\pi}x\sin(n\pi x)dx = A_n n\pi c\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2(n\pi x)dx \\
       A_n = \frac{U_0}{n\pi c}\cdot \frac{\int_{0}^{\pi}x\sin(n\pi x)dx}{\int_0^{\pi}\sin^2(n\pi x)dx}.
$$

Comment: I'm struggling to get to $$
    u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \sin(n\pi c t)\sin(n\pi x).
$$. I am unable to solve $$ T'' + n^2*pi^2*c^2*t = 0 $$

Comment: @OrangeSegments The condition $u(0,t)=0=u(1,t)$ forces the $x$ solutions to be $\sin(n\pi x)$. Then the corresponding $t$ solutions must be $A_n\sin(n\pi t)+B_n\cos(n\pi t)$, but $B_n=0$ because $u(x,0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you! As a follow-up, are the values for $$U_0$$ and $$n*pi*c$$ known?

Comment: @OrangeSegments : $U_0$ was given as part of the problem, as was $c$. $n$ must range over $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ in a sum, and the corresponding constants $A_n$ are determined by the initial condition $U_0 x = u_t(x,0)$.